# How do I extract or introspect the literal text code of a Ruby function or block?

Tags: ruby, couchdb

I'm trying to integrate working with CouchDB into the Camping web framework. Previously I was using S Expressions to parse simple Ruby blocks into JavaScript, and just writing inline JavaScript in strings when I needed something more complex.

Then I discovered the [View Server](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server), and I want to move to using Ruby for the Map and Reduce functions.

At the moment, I can do something like this:

```
view = CouchDB::View.new :myview do
    map do |doc|
        emit(doc._id, doc.price) if doc.kind == "Product"
    end
    reduce do |values|
        return sum(values)
    end
end
```

I'd like to be able to have a similar syntax for that, but for the actual text of those blocks (or methods, or whatever) to be something I can directly read and push to the database that stores the views. Is this possible to do in a way that's not really evil, like just putting them in a string, or reading the file and parsing it somehow for the text of the views?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [ruby2ruby](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby2ruby) to parse the contents of the block.

It will give you the tokenized version of the block, but not the literal text as the markup is discarded when the source is compiled into bytecode.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. I guess then I could write my own simple view server that could handle the bytecode. It'd be nice to keep the views human-readable, though.

Comment: The `rdoc` documentation generator is able to index methods and identify blocks of source, so you might want to look there to see if that works for you.